# I want to avoid ForeignKeyViolation while keeping self-reference constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I do an initial insert on a table with a self-reference constraint like this, it will be a ForeignKeyViolation (done in Postgres) because the prev_id does not exist yet.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
    prev_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (prev_id) REFERENCES hoge (id),
);
```

How can I do an INSERT without breaking the self-reference constraint?

It would be nice to remove the NOT NULL constraint on the prev_id as a first insert countermeasure, but I thought it would be pointless to have this constraint missing on subsequent inserts.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a deferred constraint, you cant, because "NOT NULL" constraint cannot be deferred:

> NOT NULL and CHECK constraints are not deferrable

From documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtable.html

If you mean that first record need to be special and have not a prev_id, you need to modify your design.